# Ruby Method Versioning

Tags: ruby, module, versioning

I'm looking for a way to advance a set of methods wrapped in a method.  Depending on input from users, a certain version of a set of methods needs to be used, but I'm wanting to know how to best version the system.  Is there a way I can avoid loads of conditionals and repetitive code?

What I'm currently considering:

```
module Module_3
  def self.alpha()
    puts 'alpha 3'
  end
end

module Module_4
  def self.alpha()
    puts 'alpha 4'
  end
end

module Module_5
  def self.alpha()
    puts 'alpha 5'
  end
end

version = 4

case version
when 3, 6
  include Module_3
when 4
  include Module_4
else
  include Module_5
end
```

The issue with this is the method call.  I would have to use the module namespace in front:

```
Module_4.alpha       # => alpha 4
```

So that hard coding means there really is no efficient way around this, that I can find.  The `case` method cannot penetrate a `method` as the scope keeps it unavailable to any conditional inside the `method` to make a choice.

```
module Mod
  case version       # => undefined local variable or method
  when 3, 6
    def self.alpha()
      puts 'alpha 3'
    end
  when 4
    def self.alpha()
      puts 'alpha 4'
    end
  else
    def self.alpha()
      puts 'alpha 5'
    end
  end
end

include Mod
```

Again, the question:  Is there a way I can avoid loads of conditionals and repetitive code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use a module, my approach would be something similar to @engineersmnky [last example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51661750/ruby-method-versioning), although would use `load` as opposed to `require`.

This script would be loaded with the main application. (simplified)

```
class MyModule

  def self.init_version(version)
    file = case version
    when 3, 6 then './my_module_3.rb'
    when 4 then './my_module_4.rb'
    when 5 then './my_module_5.rb'
    else raise RunTimeError, "invalid versions specified - #{version}"
    end
    load file
  end
end
```

Then you would have separate scripts for each behavior you need for each version.

`mymodule_3.rb`

```
class MyModule

  def self.alpha
    puts 'alpha 3'
  end
end
```

`mymodule_4.rb`

```
class MyModule

  def self.alpha
    puts 'alpha 4'
  end

end
```

`mymodule_5.rb`

```
class MyModule

  def self.alpha
    puts 'alpha 5'
  end
end
```

Once you get the version you need to process, invoke `MyModule.init_version(version)`, and the appropriate method will be loaded into `MyModule`. If the version changes, you can recall `init_version` to have the methods be overwritten with the required ones. `require` will not reload the scripts once they are already loaded, but `load` will.

This is still not "ideal", but more flexible without checking versions with each method call. Depending on your situation, it may not be necessary at all to have the ability to change versions during execution. You would maintain the ability to use consistent method calls, but so long as you load the correct version, each method will be specific for that version.

Answer (score 2):

While I don't understand why you would want to to this.

I guess you could go with something similar to your first implementation but rather like this:

```
module Module_3
  def alpha()
    puts 'alpha 3'
  end
end

module Module_4
  def alpha()
    puts 'alpha 4'
  end
end

module Module_5
  def alpha()
    puts 'alpha 5'
  end
end

version = 4
Mod = Module.new.send(:include, 
  case version
    when 3, 6
      Module_3
    when 4
      Module_4
    else
      Module_5
  end)
include Mod
```

Then you can just use `Mod` e.g. `Mod.alpha` (regardless of `version`).

Additionally if you were to put them in separate filed then simply have 1 module name would be fine and you can make the `require` conditional like.

```
case version
  when 3, 6
    require_relative 'mod_3.rb'
  when 4
    require_relative 'mod_4.rb'
  else
    require_relative 'mod_5.rb'
end
include Mod # where module Mod is defined in each of the above files
```

Comment: Users are uploading a spreadsheet with a "version number" in it.  The structure of this file might change, so I've put in a version number in a field.  I test to decide how to proceed post-upload.

Comment: Would personally prefer to use `load` instead of `require` in this case to support different versions being used within the same application. They can be dynamically overwritten each time the required version is changed if swapping around different versions. May not be needed at all in OP's case, it is unclear, but would be more flexible.

Comment: @ForeverZero I can agree although I hate the implementation all together and if there were more context chances are this is better suited for a class based implementation than a module based one.

Comment: @engineersmnky Agreed :)